# Two datalist with radiobutton in one aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, radio-button, datalist

I have two datalists in one aspx page. I need to ensure that only one radiobutton can be selected for each datalist. However , I can only manage to do it for both the datalists, which means when I click on the radiobutton on datalist1 and when I select another radiobutton on datalist2, it only allows me to choose one radiobutton. I need to make it that when I select one radiobutton on datalist1, I am also able to select another on datalist2.

Can someone help me?

Below is the javascript in aspx page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function CheckOnes(spanChk) {


    var oItem = spanChk.children;
    var theBox = (spanChk.type == "radio")
    spanChk : spanChk.children.item[0];

    xState = theBox.unchecked;
    elm = theBox.form.elements;

    for (i = 0; i < elm.length; i++)
        if (elm[i].type == "radio" && elm[i].id != theBox.id) {
            elm[i].checked = xState;
        }
    }

    function CheckTwos(spanChk2) {


        var oItem2 = spanChk2.children;
        var theBox2 = (spanChk2.type == "radio")
        spanChk2 : spanChk2.children.item[0];

        xState2 = theBox2.unchecked;
        elm2 = theBox2.form.elements;

        for (i = 0; i < elm2.length; i++)
            if (elm2[i].type == "radio" && elm2[i].id != theBox2.id) {
                elm2[i].checked = xState2;
            }
    }
```

Below is the code in aspx.cs

```
protected void DataList2_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rdb;
    rdb = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("radioDelete");
    if (rdb != null) 
       rdb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckTwos(this);");
}

protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rdb;
    rdb = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("radioAdd");
    if (rdb != null)
        rdb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckOnes(this);");

}
```

Comment: When you pass "this" to CheckOnes/CheckTwos , it basically looks for all radiobuttons within the container page. Instead pass the individual DataList instance and check.

Comment: Which means i change it to CheckOnes(DataList1) and CheckTwos(DataList2) ?

Comment: It should be (sender as DataList) instead of (this)

Comment: rdb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CheckOnes(sender as DataList);");
? It still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You need just to have for any group of radiobuttons to be with the same name.

```
Group1 :
    <input type="radio" name="group1" />
    <input type="radio" name="group1" />
Group2 :
    <input type="radio" name="group2" />
    <input type="radio" name="group2" />
Group3 :
    <input type="radio" name="group3" />
    <input type="radio" name="group3" />
```